# VBA regex in MS Word: match a new line

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace with a single *new line* this pattern with a regex in a macro (I can't use wildcard):
*new line*
digits
*new line*

In notepad++ I use this pattern `\r\n\d+\r\n` and I replace by `\r\n`

In VBA, despite what I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) (and many other threads) I had to use `\r` to match a new line. So, so far this is my script:

```
Sub regex()
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    On Error Resume Next
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = "\r\d+\r"
    ActiveDocument.Range = RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "\r")
End Sub
```

But,  this doesn't replace my pattern with a *new line* but with the characters `\` and `r` (as if regex.replace couldn't interpret regex pattern). 
So I am left with a document with many `\r` everywhere.

How can I force regex.replace to understand that I want to replace with a regex pattern?

(I have the same problem when I replace by `\s`)

Comment: You should use `vbCr`, in Excel VBA, string literals do not support escape sequences.

Comment: The trick is to replace the `ActiveDocument.Range` line with  `ActiveDocument.Range = RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "" & vbCr & "")`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, but then what you I use instead of `\s`?

Comment: `RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, vbCr)`. `\s` is a *regex pattern*, it is just a ``\`` and `s` (2 chars) in the replacement string.

Comment: Thanks for the simplify version. vbCr creates a new line, but what you I use to replace with a simple space?

Comment: What a strange question. Use `" "`.

Comment: You're right, that was a stupid question